# Window.open + href replace and pop into new window but not using target _blank

Tags: javascript, window, href

i'm stuck on something where i want the Test 1 and Test 2 links to pop-open in a new window, **not** target=_blank into a new window so the pop-up doesn't open as a tab in firefox, etc. The `"href"` in the javascript is to populate the href `#` in the Test 1 and Test 2 links. What am I doing wrong with this so I can also get the pop open into a new window but not as a target _blank?

```
<p><a id="test1" href="#">Test 1</a></p>
<p><a id="test2" href="#">Test 2</a></p>

<script> 
if(chatlink_flag == 'true')
{ 
document.getElementById('test1')window.open.href('http://www.example.com/chat1/open.htm','window1','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 
document.getElementById('test2')window.open.href('http://www.example.com/chat2/open.htm','window2','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 
}else{ 
document.getElementById('test1')window.open.href('http://www.example.com/chat1/closed.htm','window1','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 
document.getElementById('test2')window.open.href('http://www.example.com/chat2/closed.htm','window2','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems ok except that it is missing the "javascript:" part.

So you might try doing the window.open lines like this:

```
document.getElementById('test1').href = "javascript:window.open('http://www.yourpage.com/', 'window1', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no')";
```

Comment: Thank you as this solved my problem. Also, by adding "void" and then (open) prevented the returned value of [object Window] message from appearing:

document.getElementById('test1').href = "javascript:void(open('http://www.yourpage.com/', 'window1','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'))";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expected that code to do, but the following should work for you:

```
<p><a id="test1" href="#" onclick="open_window(1);">Test 1</a></p>
<p><a id="test2" href="#" onclick="open_window(2);">Test 2</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

function open_window(id) {
    if (chatlink_flag) {
        window.open('http://www.example.com/chat' + id + '/open.htm','window' + id,'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
    }
    else {
        window.open('http://www.example.com/chat' + id + '/closed.htm','window' + id,'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not able to add onclicks to my links. its such a drab not being able too. our links are managed within a cms and onclicks are't available for us. :(

Comment: in that case just change the hrefs to "javascript:open_window(1);", "javascript:open_window(2);" etc. Alternatively you could use jQuery to bind event handlers to the anchors.